# Como varrer dados igual o google?

Tags: php, python, google, big-data

Boa noite como posso fazer uma aplicação que basicamente funcione como o google, quero digitar uma palavra-chave e receber resultados sobre, ou puxar dados do próprio google, qual linguagem e caminho devo usar?

Comment: como o google buscador? ou Google bigquery? A google tem varias ferramentas.

Comment: como o google buscador

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/, assim pode usar com "qualquer linguagem", já que funciona via requisição HTTP.

Referencia: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

```
if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {

    $busca = $_GET['q'];

    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=<SUA CHAVE DA API>&cx=<SUA CHAVE CX>&q=' . rawurlencode($busca);

    $body = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($body);

    if ($json->items){
       foreach ($json->items as $item){
          print_r($item);
       }
    }
}
```

Para gerar a chave CX vá neste link: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#cx

Para gerar a chave de API neste link: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Note que a google fornece 100 consultas gratuitas por dia, para mais consultas você terá que ver o plano pago que atualmente (27/04/2018) custa $5 (creio que em dolar) para cada 1000 consultas.

Plano pago: https://developers.google.com/console/help/#billing